# Como customizar a seta padrão da tag <details>?

Tags: html, css, html5

Estou usando a tag HTML5 [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) para que o usuário, ao clicar, visualize algumas informações de uma determinada palavra. Por exemplo:

```html
<details>
  <summary>JavaScript (Clique aqui)</summary>
  <p>JavaScript é uma linguagem de programação interpretada. Foi originalmente implementada como parte dos navegadores web para que scripts pudessem ser executados do lado do cliente e interagissem com o usuário sem a necessidade deste script passar pelo servidor, controlando o navegador, realizando comunicação assíncrona e alterando o conteúdo do documento exibido. (fonte: Wikipedia)</p>
</details>
```

Os navegadores que testei que suportam essa tag (Chrome, Opera e Firefox — *infelizmente os da Microsoft não suportam*) renderizam o ícone da tag no padrão ▶, como mostra o exemplo acima ou como ilustra a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para harmonizar melhor ao layout que estou fazendo, como eu poderia customizar esse ícone, ou seja, alterar a cor, tamanho... ou é possível, até mesmo, alterar o próprio ícone ▶ por outro usando CSS?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Para ocultar o marcador/indicador de um elemento details usando apenas CSS, é possível utilizar a propriedade "display" e definir o valor "none" para o seletor "::webkit-details-marker" dentro do seletor "summary". Assim:

```
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none
}
```

Em seguida, pode-se utilizar a criatividade para personalizar a aparência do elemento summary. Por exemplo, é possível adicionar um "+" quando o elemento details estiver fechado e um "-" quando estiver aberto, para indicar a ação de expandir e recolher o conteúdo. Para isso, pode-se utilizar a pseudo-classe "before" para adicionar conteúdo antes do elemento summary. Assim:

```css
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none
}
summary:after {
  background: black; 
  content: "+"; 
  color: #fff; 
  float: left;  
  font-weight: bold; 
  padding: 0; 
  text-align: center; 
  width: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
details[open] summary:after {
  content: "-";
}
```

```html
                <details>
  <summary> JavaScript (Clique aqui)</summary>
  <p>JavaScript é uma linguagem de programação interpretada. Foi originalmente implementada como parte dos navegadores web para que scripts pudessem ser executados do lado do cliente e interagissem com o usuário sem a necessidade deste script passar pelo servidor, controlando o navegador, realizando comunicação assíncrona e alterando o conteúdo do documento exibido. (fonte: Wikipedia)</p>
</details>
```

Criei o arquivo *[change_marker_sumary_html5.css](https://github.com/cleidimarviana/SOpt/blob/master/CSS/change_marker_sumary_html5.css)* no Github para futuras referências.

Também é possível você inserir uma imagem de uma URL ou localmente, inserindo como *background* e colocando transparência no marcador *default*. Veja:

```css
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/right-arrow.svg);
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>JavaScript (Clique aqui)</summary>
  <p>JavaScript é uma linguagem de programação interpretada. Foi originalmente implementada como parte dos navegadores web para que scripts pudessem ser executados do lado do cliente e interagissem com o usuário sem a necessidade deste script passar pelo servidor, controlando o navegador, realizando comunicação assíncrona e alterando o conteúdo do documento exibido. (fonte: Wikipedia)</p>
</details>
```

Veja também no HTML5 Doctor [outros detalhes](http://html5doctor.com/the-details-and-summary-elements/) e no [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-that-details-summary-is-the-easiest-way-ever-to-make-an-accordion/).

Comment: Mt bom os exemplos. Vai servir de base tranquilo. Obg!

Answer (score 2):

Para alterar o ícone você pode usar o atributo list-style-type que é compatível com os principais navegadores da seguinte maneira:

```css
summary{
    list-style-type: '♣';
    color: #191970;
}

details[open] summary{
    list-style-type: '♦';
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary> JavaScript (Clique aqui)</summary>
  <p>JavaScript é uma linguagem de programação interpretada. Foi originalmente implementada como parte dos navegadores web para que scripts pudessem ser executados do lado do cliente e interagissem com o usuário sem a necessidade deste script passar pelo servidor, controlando o navegador, realizando comunicação assíncrona e alterando o conteúdo do documento exibido. (fonte: Wikipedia)</p>
</details>
```

veja mais sobre este atributo e sua compatibilidade em https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

assim dá certo:

```
summary{list-style: none;}
```