# ::active + CSS não está funcionando

Tags: css, css3

```css
div.duvidas2 > div > div::active + 
div.duvidas2 > div > article {
  display: block;
}
div.duvidas2 > div > article {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class=duvidas2>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Titulo 1</span>
      <label>+</label>  
    </div>
    <article>Artigo 1.</article>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Titulo 2</span>
      <label>+</label>  
    </div>
    <article>Artigo 2.</article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Meu objetivo é clicar na `div.duvidas2 > div` e abrir o `article`
Mas apenas o `article` da `div.duvidas2 > div` que estiver ativa deve estar com `display:block`

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara está tudo errado...

Active não tem dois dois-pontos, não é assim `::active`, é assim `:active`

Não adianta colocar `:active` em uma `div`, pq `:active` não é uma propriedade desse tipo de elemento, `:active` é para usar em `links` e alguns elementos de `form`, mas não em uma `div`

A regra tb está equivocada...

```
div.duvidas2 > div > div::active + 
div.duvidas2 > div > article
```

Primeiro que vc está usando o `+` que pegaria uma `div` com a classe `div.duvidas2` que vem depois da primeira `div` com `div.duvidas2`, só que vc só tem uma `div.duvidas2` então a regra já não bate...

É nessas coisas ai que vc está errando

Agora pelo que entendi do que vc quer, uma opção seria usando uma tag `<a>` e a pseudo classe `:focus`, assim quando vc clicar no  vai fazer o focus e mostrar o `<article>` com uma regra CSS tipo `a:focus + article {display:block}`

```css
div.duvidas2 > div > a + article {
    display: none;
}
div.duvidas2 > div > a:focus + article {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class=duvidas2>

  <div>
    <a href="#">
      <span>Titulo 1</span>
      <label>+</label>  
    </a>
    <article>Artigo 1.</article>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="#">
      <span>Titulo 2</span>
      <label>+</label>  
    </a>
    <article>Artigo 2.</article>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sobre os :: é regra do CSS3. : apenas era no CSS2. Mas no caso hugocsl, tem como, ao clicar no mesmo link, fechar ele também? Tipo: abriu, clica de novo e fechou. Isso com CSS? Ou no caso só dá com JS? Mas entendi sua explicação. Mas, o link mostra um exemplo com input type text https://jsfiddle.net/zsderorm/1/

Comment: @CarlosRocha não jovem, não existe `::active` em lugar nenhum, aqui vc pode conferir uma documentação confiável e vai ver que não tem menção a `::active`, os `::` são para pseudo-elementos, não para pseudo-classe veja https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes esse exemplo do link que vc postou usa `:focus` como o exemplo que eu deixei ai na resposta. Do jeito que vc quer da pra fazer tb, mas a técnica é outra, é usando checkbox e label. Ou então vc pode fazer como nessa questão https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360001/como-customizar-a-seta-padr%c3%a3o-da-tag-details

Comment: entendi! Nesse caso, fazer com JavaScript ou JQuery vai ficar melhor! Mas muito obrigado. Vou aceitar a resposta pois foi compatível totalmente com a pergunta!

Comment: @CarlosRocha haha pois vc perguntou onde estava errando né rss. Mas para resolver existem várias tecnicas, algumas sim com JS/jQuery, mas tb dá pra fazer com html/css, procure por "Collapse component" no Google que vc vai achar algumas coisas. Essa outra questão tb pode te interessar tem umas dicas lá https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182123/como-fazer-collapse-e-expand-de-um-texto-usando-apenas-html5